# Custom validations for link field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a model with a `link` attribute. The link attribute can be set to either an external url e.g.: `http://google.com` or reference an internal page e.g.: `/users/1`.

In the form `link` is just a text field with no validation. It is rendered with `link_to "whatever", model.link`.

There are lots of examples of URI validation for rails. However, none I've found take into account relative paths as well. I was considering using a regex, but wanted to know if there was a better way of setting up a `link` attribute that can handle external (http/https) and internal (/users/1, /locations, /whatever/1/something/2) paths.

**Examples of what should be allowed**

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://www.google.com?something=blah
http://www.google.com/thing/test/
/locations
/locations/1
/products/1/skus/4
"" (e.g. blank)
```

**Examples of what should not be allowed**

```
www.google.com
google.com
products/2
htt://
```

**Edit**

If there is a better, completely different approach to this I'm open to that as well.

Comment: regex won't be enough, given your requirement of reference urls.  (what happens if a user puts /google?)  would suggest to have a uniform set of rules for all URLs.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that strict. This tool is only accessible by admins so really I'm just looking to meet the minimum validation. If they entered `/google` it would like to a page that doesn't exist and be re-directed to 404. What I'm trying to accomplish is making sure the admins follow the correct format and don't accidentally miss a slash or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because only admins will be using this filed I only needed minimum validation to ensure that the correct prefix was entered (so that a character wasn't accidentally missed) I ended up going with this:

```
validates :link, :format => /(^$)|(^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/))/ix
```

If anyone has a better solution I'm open to changing it.